# When I open the app I get: the {name app} stopped working

Tags: android, webview

My code for android webview.

```
package me.filtering.netsparkmobile;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;

import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.filtering.me");
```

My problem: When I open the app I get: the {name app} stopped working.

Comment: Please post the logcat error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not setting a content view, do this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_with_your_webview);
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.filtering.me");
}
```

I would suggest reading up some more on [Android](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html) or potentially take an online [course](https://www.udacity.com/courses/android).